# Why does the third iteration does not take place in the Loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
num = 5
if num > 2:
   print(num)
   num-=1
print(num)
```

For the first iteration num =5 and 5>2 num =4, for second iteration num = 4 and 4>2 num= 3.
Why does the third iteration does not take place? While comipling the code the output is 5,4 but i was expection 5,4,3 because as 3 is greater than 2. Can anyone please do help me out on this issue.

Thanks

Comment: You are not looping.

Comment: Wheres the loop?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for asking a great question. One quick clarification: I see  an `if` statement, but I don't see a loop. Could you share that, too? If there's no loop, that's your answer. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `if` is not an iteration command, it's a selection command.

The `if` statement here will run once and once only, with `5` being output inside the `if` and `4` being output by the final `print` statement, *after* the `if` is done.

If you want iteration, you need `while`, something like (without the final `print`, giving `5, 4, 3`):

```py
num = 5
while num > 2:
   print(num)
   num -= 1
```